# Does entity framework lazy loading works automatically when I use virtual?

Tags: entity-framework

I was wondering does lazy loading just works when I use virtual or I have to explicitly set it to true, like so:

```
DbContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The true is there are other requirements you must meet if you want to enable lazy loading and to have Entity Framework track changes in your classes as the changes occur. You can find these requirements in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx):

> For either of these proxies to be created:
>
> - A custom data class **must be** declared with `public` access.
> - A custom data class **must not be** `sealed` (`NotInheritable` in Visual    Basic)
> - A custom data class **must not be** `abstract` (`MustInherit` in Visual    Basic).
> - A custom data class **must have** a `public` or `protected` **constructor that    does not have parameters**. Use a `protected` constructor without    parameters if you want the `Create`
>     method to be used to create a  proxy for the POCO entity. Calling
>     the `Create` method does not guarantee the creation of the
>     proxy: the POCO class must follow the    other requirements that are
>     described in this topic.
> - The class **cannot implement** the `IEntityWithChangeTracker` or    `IEntityWithRelationships` interfaces because the proxy classes implement these interfaces.
>
>   The `ProxyCreationEnabled` option must be set to `true`.
>
> For lazy loading proxies:
>
> - Each navigation property must be declared as `public`, `virtual`    (`Overridable` in Visual Basic), and not `sealed` (`NotOverridable` in
>     Visual Basic) get accessor. The navigation property defined in the  custom data class must have a corresponding navigation property in
>     the conceptual model.
>
> For change tracking proxies:
>
> - Each property that is mapped to a property of an entity type in the    data model **must have** `non-sealed` (`NotOverridable` in Visual
>     Basic),    `public`, and `virtual` (`Overridable` in Visual Basic) get
>     and set    accessors.
> - A navigation property that represents the "many" end of a    relationship **must return** a type that implements `ICollection`, where
>     `T`    is the type of the object at the other end of the relationship.
> - If you want the proxy type to be created along with your object, **use**    the [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696136(v=vs.113).aspx) method on the `DBSet<T>` when creating a new  object, instead of the `new` operator.

Comment: FYI: This means that you can have private properties and [NotMapped] non-private properties and still get a change tracking proxy. I tested it & it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy)

> Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed. **When using POCO entity types, lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of derived proxy types and then overriding virtual properties to add the loading hook.** [...]

To answer your question, as long as it's enabled, yes, virtual navigation properties will be lazy-loaded.

Answer (score 0):

By default

```
DbContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled
```

is set to **true** so if you don't forget virtual and you don't mark class as sealed it works.